# Python Clik Module in WinDbg

Tags: windows, windbg, pykd

I've been using [click](http://click.pocoo.org/5/) module for some time now and I think it's awesome. However I have some problems using it in a WinDbg python plugin.

I'm using the following script, which works fine in Linux:

```
import click

@click.group()
def shell():
    pass

@shell.command()
@click.option('--name', help='Your name please')
def hello(name):
    click.echo(name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    shell()
```

A successful invocation of a script can be seen below (this is in Linux command line):

```
# python test.py hello --name=aaa
aaa
```

An unsuccessful invocation of a script can be seen below (this is in WinDbg plugin):

```
0:000> !py C:\Users\windbg\test.py hello --name=aaa
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  hello
```

Any ideas why this happens and why a WinDbg plugin doesn't accept parameters in order for them to be parsed by click correctly.

Comment: PyKd [supports regular arguments](https://pykd.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PYKD%200.2.%20Documentation&referringTitle=Documentation#windbgcommands-runningscripts). Can you check whether that works? When was that annotation/decoration syntax available in Python? Could it be a Python 2/3 version issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is click "feature":

see  click\utils.py:

```
if PY2 and WIN and _initial_argv_hash == _hash_py_argv():
    return _get_windows_argv() 
return sys.argv[1:]

def _get_windows_argv():
    argc = c_int(0)
    argv_unicode = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), byref(argc))
```

So, click gets args not from sys.args, but from windbg real commandline.

You can easy fix this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    shell(args=sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: I use karmadbg to debug your script, it takes about 5 min, enjoy :)